# 'RSACryptoServiceProvider' does not contain a definition for 'GetNonZeroBytes'

Tags: c#, asp.net, hash

I have a small problem. I'm trying to hash a password, but an error occurs.
The Error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1061  'RSACryptoServiceProvider' does not contain a definition for 'GetNonZeroBytes' and no accessible extension method 'GetNonZeroBytes' accepting a first argument of type 'RSACryptoServiceProvider' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

The code:

```
public string HashPassword(string password)
        {
            byte[] salt = new byte[128 / 8];
            using (var rngCsp = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                rngCsp.GetNonZeroBytes(salt);
                
            }
            string hashed = Convert.ToBase64String(KeyDerivation.Pbkdf2(
                password: password,
                salt: salt,
                prf: KeyDerivationPrf.HMACSHA256,
                iterationCount: 100000,
                numBytesRequested: 256 / 8));
            return hashed;
        }
```

I am using:

```
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System;
```

[I used the official APS.NET Core documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/consumer-apis/password-hashing?view=aspnetcore-6.0), but I don't know where I'm wrong.

Comment: Were you intending to use `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` (which is a random number generator) rather than `RSACryptoServiceProvider` perhaps?

Comment: Download the release file from following : https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore

Comment: @Flydog57 Wow i can't believe i didn't notice it. Thank you!

Comment: Glad I helped.  Voting to close (it's just a typo)

Answer (score 0):

**Use class RNGCryptoServiceProvider (not RSACryptoServiceProvider)**

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.KeyDerivation;

using (var rngCsp = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
{
    rngCsp.GetNonZeroBytes(salt);
}
```